# Сделать карту на весь экран

Tags: javascript, leafletjs

**Цель:** Сделать карту на весь экран без дублирования по горизонтали и верхнего "пустого пространства". 
**Проблема:** Вместо дублирования карты появились тайлы "map data no yet available"
 
Говоря конкретнее, нужно убрать тайлы где написано "map data no yet available". И чтобы при перетаскивании нельзя было тащить дальше карты, т.е. дальше границы карты не перетаскивается
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Код на JSFiddle](https://clck.ru/M9Xdn)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно вот так Вам подойдет:

```js
var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
      
var osm = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl, {
    noWrap: true
});

var map = new L.Map('map', {
    center: new L.LatLng(60, 30.3),
    layers: [osm]
});

var rect = new L.LatLngBounds(
  new L.LatLng(85, -180),  
  new L.LatLng(-85, 180)
);

map.setMinZoom(map.getBoundsZoom(rect, true));
map.fitBounds(rect); 
map.setMaxBounds(rect);
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#map {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.css"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: все просто отлично, смущает только это https://imgur.com/c9U4iB0

Comment: решено установкой зума

Comment: @MidNightElf вероятно еще 179 вместо 180 помогло бы

Comment: Чисто случайно еще заметил, эти частично пропавшие тайлы случаются если еще не подключить leaflet.css. <i>Кто знает, может кому пригодится :)</i>